# How to recognize a Cardinal type in the array of const?

Tags: delphi, rtti

I have an example, just simple case-of for different Delphi types. But VType don't have a Cardinal type. If I put a Cardinal value into parameters, it can be broke.

```delphi
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

procedure GetSomething(const Input: array of const);
var
  LIndex: Integer;
begin
  for LIndex := Low(Input) to High(Input) do
  begin
    case Input[LIndex].VType of
      vtWideString: Writeln('WideString = ''', WideString(Input[LIndex].VWideChar), '''');
      vtInt64: Writeln('Int64 = ', Input[LIndex].VInt64^);
      vtCurrency: Writeln('Currency = ', CurrToStr(Input[LIndex].VCurrency^));
      vtInteger: Writeln('Integer = ', Input[LIndex].VInteger);
      vtBoolean: Writeln('Boolean = ', BoolToStr(Input[LIndex].VBoolean, True));
      vtChar: Writeln('Char = ''', Input[LIndex].VChar, '''');
      vtExtended: Writeln('Extended = ', FloatToStr(Input[LIndex].VExtended^));
      vtString: Writeln('ShortString = ''', Input[LIndex].VString^, '''');
      vtPChar: Writeln('PChar = ''', Input[LIndex].VPChar, '''');
      vtAnsiString: Writeln('AnsiString = ''', Ansistring(Input[LIndex].VAnsiString), '''');
      vtWideChar: Writeln('WideChar = ''', Input[LIndex].VWideChar, '''');
      vtPWideChar: Writeln('PWideChar = ''', Input[LIndex].VPWideChar, '''');
      vtUnicodeString : Writeln('UnicodeString = ''', string(Input[LIndex].VUnicodeString), '''');
    else
      Writeln('Unsupported');
    end;
  end;
end;
var
  x: cardinal;
begin
  x := 3147483647;
  try
    GetSomething(['some string', 123, x, 'something else', 12.3, false]);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Output results, two integers:

```
UnicodeString = 'some string'
Integer = 123
Integer = -1147483649
UnicodeString = 'something else'
Extended = 12,3
Boolean = False
```

Comment: If you know you have a cardinal, you can always typecast the integer. Or you could use the 64-bit integral member.

Comment: You also don't have a `Word` or `Byte` or `ShortInt` or `Double` type - you have to live with what is possible and what isn't. `Integer` and `Cardinal` both use 32 bit - provide `Int64(x)` if your `Cardinal` variable uses the 32th bit or interpret it as `Cardinal(Input[LIndex].VInteger)`. The value isn't "_broke_" - it's just not spoon fed to you, because not every type can be achieved (or distinguished).

Comment: I haven't worked with `TVarRec` in a long time, but I would have expected the compiler to upscale `Byte`/`Word`/`ShortInt` to `Integer`, `Cardinal` to `Int64`, and `Double` to `Extended` to avoid data losses. But in this case, if it is really reporting a `Cardinal` as a signed `Integer`, I would consider that a bug, since there is no way to differentiate between them.

Comment: Use an `array of TValue` if you want to preserve more types than `TVarRec` supports.

Comment: @StefanGlienke TValue.Kind evaluates to tkInteger for a Cardinal, so it is no better than TVarRec in this case.

Comment: There is a difference between `tkInteger` and `vtInteger`. `Byte`, `ShortInt`, `Word`, `SmallInt`, `Integer`, and `Cardinal` are all `TTypeKind` `tkInteger`. But since a `TValue` also carries the `PTypeInfo` you can retrieve its `TOrdType` which tells you exactly what you want to know.